# react componentdidupdate provokes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, reactjs, infinite-loop

I trigger an API call to elasticsearch with `onChange` so that I can prompt a list for autocomplete.
To ensure that my store was updated before rerender I added componentDidMount so that I am not one tick behind. But getting to the point needs code, so:

```js
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    inputValue: '',
    options: []
  };
  this.props = {
    inputValue: '',
    options: []
  };
  this._onChange = this._onChange.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
  CodeStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);
}

_onChange(event) {
  if (this.state.inputValue && !event) {
    var enteredChars = this.state.inputValue;
    console.log('NO EVENT!');
  } else if (event.target.value) {
    console.log('EVENT!');
    var enteredChars = event.target.value;
    this.setState({inputValue: enteredChars});
  }
  CodeService.nextCode(enteredChars);
}
```

As you can see I added some log events just to get sure my condition is doing right. I read about that `setState` provokes a rerender so it is inside the condition but that didn't had stopped the loop . And the console log confirms the condition switch. But having the `setState` inside my condition brakes the functionality and I do not get a list.

Here is my log:

```
                        0
Home.jsx:48             EVENT!
Home.jsx:50             0
CodeService.js:27       request
CodeActions.js:10       dispatch
CodeStore.js:22         store
Home.jsx:43             1
Home.jsx:46             NO EVENT!
10OptionTemplate.jsx:15 render-list
CodeService.js:27       request
CodeActions.js:10       dispatch
CodeStore.js:22         store
Home.jsx:43             1
Home.jsx:46             NO EVENT!
10OptionTemplate.jsx:15 render-list
CodeService.js:27       request
CodeActions.js:10       dispatch
CodeStore.js:22         store
Home.jsx:43             1
Home.jsx:46             NO EVENT!
```

The infinity loop does not hurt the performance anyhow. I think because of `componentWillUnmount` but the massive amount of API calls have to be avoided. Hope this is enough information for any evidence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the infinite loop is caused by the following pattern:

1. user types input
2. _onChange updates state + fires action to store
3. Store updates itself and send change event
4. Store change event fires **same** _onChange event
5. _onChange does not update state, but fires action to store nonetheless
6. Goto step 3. and repeat (indefinitely)

Steps to take to fix:

- make different change handlers for user input and store update (as already suggested by @Janaka Stevens)
- put the data from store in state
- user input does not have to be in state (if your react code does not provide a value to an input field, it will start with empty value, and leave whatever is typed alone)

Then your code could look something like this:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    options: []
  };
  // removed the this.props bit: props should not be updated inside component
  this._onChangeUser = this._onChangeUser.bind(this);
  this._onChangeStore = this._onChangeStore.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
  CodeStore.addChangeListener(this._onChange);    // this is OK
}

_onChangeUser(event) {
  console.log('EVENT!');
  var enteredChars = event.target.value;
  CodeService.nextCode(enteredChars);
  // No need to update state here - go to sleep until store changes
}

_onChangeStore() {
  var newList = getListFromStore();  // your own function to get list from store
  this.setState({ options: newList});            // update state here
}
```

Not sure what you meant by 'one tick behind', or what could have caused it, but cleaning up endless loop is a good place to start ;)

PS: Code above is sketch only, may have typo's.

Comment: Oh great that really helped me out :). I will publish here the result later. Do you have any sources you would provide to dive deeper in the use of react?

Comment: You're welcome. As for sources: [React's own pages](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html) are a good source. I would especially recommend to watch the videos.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using _onChange for both your input event and store listener. They need separate methods.

Comment: That is correct. Even with a separate one it produces an infinite loop when I add the function to the constructor but removing it from the constructor gives me the same behaviour as before where I can in my log that I have an array of 10 but the view is rendered without. I will add the constructor to the question

Comment: If the store listener uses _onChange and _onChange uses CodeService and CodeService triggers store and store triggers onChange and onChange triggers CodeService and ...

Comment: Okay that is clear :/ The infinity loop just covered that it wasn't a real solution that I had an output. Than I will take the search for what needs to be included that it takes care for a re-render event. Thx!

Comment: Also: better to avoid doing anything after `this.setState()` at all in the same block/function. Since `setState()` triggers re-render (i.e. abandon current block or function), whatever statements you code after setState in the same block (in your case the ` CodeService.nextCode(enteredChars);`) will have unpredictable results at best.

Comment: @wintvelt good to know thx! But unfortunately it did not changed the behaviour. Do you have any other tip how the `componentDidMount` could look like? If further infos are needed I will add!